# Set minDate for Bootstrap DateTimePicker from another

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Currently, I'm using `Bootstrap 3 Datepicker` from [this source](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

I have 2 `datetimepicker` on my system. (`startTime`, `endTime`).

I tried but don't know how to set `minDate` for `endTime` from `startTime` value whenever `startTime` value changed. Even it don't jump on `change` event.

Please point me what am I missing.

**[Here is my code](http://codepen.io/manhle/pen/xVbroB?editors=1010)**

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the [change event](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange) and [minDate()](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#minmaxdate) function like

```js
$('#txtStartTime').datetimepicker({
  showTodayButton: true,
  format: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm',
  sideBySide: true,
  maxDate: moment()
}).on('dp.change', function(e) {
  $('#txtEndTime').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date)
});
$('#txtEndTime').datetimepicker({
  showTodayButton: true,
  format: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm',
  sideBySide: true
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">.</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <input class="form-control datetimepicker" id="txtStartTime" type='text' />
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <input class="form-control datetimepicker" id="txtEndTime" type='text' />
</div>
```