# How do I set Min Date in DateTimepicker from another DateTimepicker?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

I want the date on the first `DateTimePicker` to be the `MinDate` on the second one,I found some solutions but they were about `DatePicker` and doesn't work

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#arrival').datetimepicker({
                locale: "<?php echo $lang['datetimepicker_lang']; ?>",
                format: "<?php echo $lang['datetimepicker_format']; ?>",
            });


        $('#departure').datetimepicker({
            locale: "<?php echo $lang['datetimepicker_lang']; ?>",
            format: "<?php echo $lang['datetimepicker_format']; ?>",    
        });
});
```

Comment: Please explain further: Do you want the date on the first DateTimePicker to be the MinDate on the second one?

Comment: yeah that's it sorry !!

Comment: Are you  referring to twitter bootstrap 3 datepicker or another framework?

Comment: yea, is Bootstrap 3 Datepicker, is this one https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/,

Comment: I think this is it: [Set mindate for bootstrap...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713875/set-mindate-for-bootstrap-datetimepicker-from-another)

Comment: Was sure to have looked everywhere, thank you so much @AbsalonCastañon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set minDate for Bootstrap DateTimePicker from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713875/set-mindate-for-bootstrap-datetimepicker-from-another)

Comment: You are welcome Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is it: [Set mindate for bootstrap...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713875/set-mindate-for-bootstrap-datetimepicker-from-another)

THe main part is this:

```
on('dp.change', function(e) {
  $('#txtEndTime').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date)
```

Here you are using the [event options](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/) of datetimepicker, so each time you change its value it will use the [minDate function](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#minmaxdate) to set the minDate of the other datetimepicker.

Comment: Thank you @Absalon Castañon you are the boss !